# how to auto center an image in a div, when he is resized

Tags: html, css

I'm making a site that contains some cards of discord users. I put the avatar in a div, and when I hover this, the image expands, but it is going more to the left. I put a border in the card example below to better visualization:

If you see on the right of image when hovered, it is getting closer to the left of the box, while on the left it is fixed. Does anyone know how to make it self-center when it expands, or else, when it goes over, the width of the box also increases along with the height, which already is it increasing automatically in this code?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@1,200&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
}

#accounts {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.acc {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 60px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: aqua;
  width: 200px;
}

.icons {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.75s;
  object-fit: contain;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icons:hover {
  width: 250px;
}

.nick {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#nc1 {
  margin-right: 13px;
}

#nc2 {
  margin-left: 9px;
}

#sc-btn {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#sc-btn a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sc-btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

#server-button {
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: 0.75s;
}

#sv-btn-text {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  transition: 0.75s;
}

#server-button:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

#server-button:hover #sv-btn-text {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="accounts">
  <div class="acc" id="luiz">
    <a href="https://instagram.com/luizzz28_" target="_blank">
      <img class="icons" src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/YBEo2ls8xQBT9HVGHsYwkZm3dddiQNZ_njgmk7kHClc/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/707608125825482894/7c8b1fc2a14f2b47122bb3ac5c5bedb1.png">
    </a>
    <h2 class="nick" id="nc1">luizzz#0001</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="acc">
    <a href="https://instagram.com/dmn.juniorr" target="_blank">
      <img class="icons" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/799372092108832778/6788af224fd81da075b0b05f4e42d4a6.png?size=1024">
    </a>
    <h2 class="nick" id="nc2">juniorr ƉємƠη#5456</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<section id="sc-btn">
  <a href="https://discord.gg/tcQhcVG">
    <div id="server-button">
      <h1 id="sv-btn-text">demoninhos</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</section>

<div id="lateral-menu"></div>
```

Comment: if you have transform: scale(1.2); on the image you can also put transform-origin: center; you increased the width from 200px to 250px? instead add transform scale on :hover and transform origin on icon

Comment: thx, but its the same of the another guy that answered, if i use transform, the another elements, not move along with the image, test and you see, the nicks and the button "demoninhos" dont move, they got fixed

Comment: `.acc:hover {transform: scale(2);} .acc {transform-origin: center'}` @softzzz

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the width attribute on hover, try using the `transform: scale()` attribute and using the `transform-origin` attribute set to the center. You can use pixels, or percent, or whatever with the transform, I just picked a number for the example. You can learn more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@1,200&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

body {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.accounts {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.acc {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 60px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: aqua;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 0;
}

.icons {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    transition: 0.75s;
    object-fit: contain;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.icons:hover {
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

.nick {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#nc1 {
    margin-right: 13px;
}

#nc2 {
    margin-left: 9px;
}

#sc-btn {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

#sc-btn a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#sc-btn a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 8px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}


#server-button {   
    padding: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border-color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 0.75s;
}

#sv-btn-text {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: 0.75s;
}



#server-button:hover {
    background-color: white;
}

#server-button:hover #sv-btn-text {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>$$$$$</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./src/favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="accounts">
            <div class="acc" id="luiz">
                <a href="https://instagram.com/luizzz28_" target="_blank">
                    <img class="icons" src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/YBEo2ls8xQBT9HVGHsYwkZm3dddiQNZ_njgmk7kHClc/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/707608125825482894/7c8b1fc2a14f2b47122bb3ac5c5bedb1.png">
                </a>
                <h2 class="nick" id="nc1">luizzz#0001</h2>
            </div>
            </div>
       <div class="accounts">
            <div class="acc">
                <a href="https://instagram.com/dmn.juniorr" target="_blank">
                    <img class="icons" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/799372092108832778/6788af224fd81da075b0b05f4e42d4a6.png?size=1024">
                </a>
                <h2 class="nick" id="nc2">juniorr ƉємƠη#5456</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
           </div>
        <section id="sc-btn">
            <a href="https://discord.gg/tcQhcVG">
                <div id="server-button">
                    <h1 id="sv-btn-text">demoninhos</h1>
                </div>
            </a>
        </section>

        <div id="lateral-menu"></div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: well, it works, but it doesn't look the way I want, I want the other elements to also move along with the expansion of the image, as you told me, the nicks and the button "demoninhos" button remain in their place before, some another solution? if not, I appreciate the help anyway <33

Comment: I added `padding-bottom: 15px` which will push the elements below the profile icons down as you hover, but it does change the container size as well.

Comment: @softzzz Take a look at my most recent edit. I changed `accounts` to a class instead of an id so you can use it multiple times and keep the layout for that. I then put your accounts into a flex box `container` which will allow you to get the hover effect you desire without affecting the container sizing. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For CSS:

```
background-image: background-posution: center;
```

For img:

```
<div align=center><img src=... style=width:50vw;></div>
```